# VSCode SSH-Remote - listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my website using the Remote-SSH Extension with VSCode.

Unfortunately I'm getting this error "listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1" when trying to connect to the server.

I have no issues connecting to it with the regular terminal and accessing my website files and creating/removing files inside it.

I saw people suggesting to delete the /.vscode-server folder but I don't have such a folder or file on my machine.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.